# Bash problem with regular expressions in conditional expressions

Tags: regex, bash

I am attempting to use a regular expression within a Bash conditional expression and Bash does not like my syntax. The code follows:

```
    declare -a sshkeys
    declare sshpath="$HOME/.ssh"
    if [[ -f "$sshpath/ssh_keys" ]]; then
        mapfile -t sshkeys <"$sshpath/ssh-keys"
    fi
    declare pattern="^(:alnum::alnum:*)(:blank:|#|$)"
    for i in {"$sshkeys[@]"}
    do
        if [[ [ "$i" ~= "$pattern" ] && [ -e "$sshpath/$BASH_REMATCH[1]" ] ]]; then
            ssh-add "$sshpath/$BASH_REMATCH[1]" </dev/null 1>&-
        fi
    done
```

Bash produces the following error message:

```
source .profile
bash: .profile: line 49: conditional binary operator expected
bash: .profile: line 49: syntax error near `"$i"'
bash: .profile: line 49: `        if [[ [ "$i" ~= "$pattern" ] && [ -e "$sshpath/$BASH_REMATCH[1]" ] ]]; then'
```

It looks like Bash is not happy with regular expression tests in complex conditional expressions. Can anyone say how I should be doing this?

Comment: Did you mean `pattern='^([[:alnum:]]*)([[:blank:]#]|$)'`?

Comment: what's in `$i`? what does `echo ${i}` show?

Comment: Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance, though it probably can't guess what you mean when you're this far off.

Comment: Wiktor Stribizew The expression must have a least one alphanumeric character but may contain more and is delimited by one of a white space character, a # signaling the start of a comment or a $ for end of line.

Comment: @mark-fuso It contains the file name of a file in a directory which is then combined with the path to the directory to access the file.

Comment: I modified the script to  use nested if statements and got the following result:
```
bash: [: ~=: binary operator expected
bash: [: ~=: binary operator expected
~~~
The relevant source code follows:
```
        if [ "$i" ~= $pattern ]; then
            if [[ -f "$sshpath/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" ]]; then              
                ssh-add "$sshpath/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" </dev/null 1>&-
            fi
        fi
```

Comment: `for i in {"$sshkeys[@]"}`, while it will work, it will add an unwanted prefix of `{` on the first array item, and add an unwanted suffix of `}` on the last array item ... hence my suggestion to verify that `$i` does in fact contain what you think it does

Comment: also, the nested square braces ... `[[ [ ... ] && [ ... ] ]]` is invalid; see Benjamin's answer for a fix; alternatively you can replace the internal `[]`'s with parens, eg, `[[ ( ... ) && ( ... ) ]]`

Answer (score 2):

- There seems to be a typo (`ssh_keys`, but then `ssh-keys`)
- You're using incorrect character classes in the regular expression: it should probably be something like

  ```
  ^([[:alnum:]]+)([[:blank:]]|#|$)
  ```
- To loop over array elements, use

  ```
  for i in "${sshkeys[@]}"
  ```
- The operator to compare to a regex is `=~`, not `~=`
- The pattern must be *unquoted* after `=~`, or it is interpreted as a literal string
- You can't do this for multiple conditions:

  ```
  [[ [ cond1 ] && [ cond2 ] ]]
  ```

  but have to use this:

  ```
  [[ cond1 ]] && [[ cond2 ]]
  ```

  or this:

  ```
  [[ cond1 && cond2 ]]
  ```

  with parentheses as required
- Array element access has to look like this:

  ```
  ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  ```

Comment: I tried using `[[ cond1 ]] && [[ cond2 ]]` and got the same result.

Comment: I added all your suggestions but I am still getting the Bash problem.

Comment: @Jonathan Oh, I missed one. The operator is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The problem turned out to be a typo on my part. I was using ~= instead of =~ as the regular expression operator and misinterpreted the diagnostics.

Comment: There's about half a dozen other problems, many of which are pointed out in Benjamin's answer. Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.